# GridView cell not registering any controls on RowCommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

First off, I realize most of this can also be done using ItemTemplates. If what I'm trying to do simply isn't possible, I will consider using them instead.

Here are the basics of my dilemma:

I have a GridView in the ASPX page that is loaded in the CodeBehind. Each row contains a couple of buttons that trigger the OnRowCommand event. When someone clicks the "Edit" button, I create a TextBox object and add it to the Controls collection of a particular cell.

This works fine.

The problem is, when the person clicks the "Save" button, OnRowCommand is triggered again but the cell is registering 0 items in the Controls collection. I'm pretty sure this is happening before a PostBack so I'm not sure why I can't access the TextBox control.

I checked after initially adding the TextBox and it shows 1 Control in the cell. Somewhere between loading the page with the textboxes and clicking the button, these controls have gone missing. Google wasn't much help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dynamically creating textboxes so you have to re-bind your grid on each post back, give your textboxes and id (always the same) and re-attach any event handlers.

Comment: I didn't realize the controls were getting lost in the postback. Ended up just getting the values I wanted from the 'Request.Form' object. Still wish it was a bit easier to perpetuate the controls without creating TemplateFields for everything.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the edit button, you are in edit mode for the GridView.  You need to set that up as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating controls on the fly, they will always disappear on postback, meaning that you will have to keep creating them on every cycle through.

I would personally suggest sticking with ItemTemplates and keeping yourself a little bit more free from the headaches that all of this can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an addhandler with a delegate when you create your button behind the code. the handler will fire before the rowcommand will.

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated

Dim btnsave As New ImageButton
If e.Row.RowType <> DataControlRowType.Pager And e.Row.RowType <>  DataControlRowType.Header Then
    AddHandler btnedit.Click, AddressOf btnedit_Click
    GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Controls.Add(btndel)
end if

end sub

Public Delegate Sub ImageClickEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
Sub btnedit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)

//do whatever you want here.
//possibly a redirect to the current page so nothing else fires

end sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the code example but I ended up with another solution. Thanks.